# Is it always possible to simultaneously slice two rain drops each exactly in half with a single straight-line cut?

Tags: calculus, continuity

In theory, can you always simultaneously slice two rain drops on the windscreen each exactly in half with a single straight-line cut, no matter the shapes of the rain drops nor their location on the windscreen? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is possible. The drops are in 3-dimensional space. and a 2-dimensional plane can cut them both to half.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem